# Is $x_1^2-x_2^3$ irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Is the polynomial $f=x_1^2-x_2^3 \in K[x_1,x_2]$, with $K$ field, irreducible? I think yes, because:

- $f=x_1^2-x_2^3$ has degree $3$. If suppose that $f=hk$ is a non trivial factorisation, than deg$h=1$ and deg$k=2$. Then i write $h=ax_1+bx_2+c$ and $k=a'x_1^2+b'x_2^2+c'$ (i don't write $k=a'x_1^2+b'x_2^2+c'+d'x_1x_2$ because in $f$ there isn't the mixed product $x_1x_2$). Then multiplyng and imposing the equality between $f$ and $hk$ i find that $aa'=0; \quad  ab'=0; \quad ac'=0$, so i can conclude $a=0$ otherwise $k=0$ and that is absurd. Continuing, i have also $ba'=0; \quad bb'=-1; \quad bc'=0$, so i conclude that $b\neq0$ and $a'=c'=0$. But now in $hk$ doesn't compare the monomial $x_1^2$. Absurd.
- Is correct my reasoning?
- Are there other ways to prove this irreducibility? In genereal which are the "tricks" or observations one can use to prove irreducibility of polynomial in such cases?

Comment: You cannot suppose $d'=0$ because when you multiply the mixed term may cancel.

Comment: The idea of your approach is valid, however to make it into a correct proof you must include all possible terms in $k$. Don't assume they are zero. A priori, $k$ could have $x_1 x_2$ term, also $x_1$ and $x_2$ (linear) terms; in principle, the $x_1 x_2$ term from $k$ could maybe cancel out, when the linear terms from $h$ are multiplied with the linear terms in $k$. If you want to have a proof with the kind of reasoning that you wrote, then you should include all those terms in $k$, and then rule them out.

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ is a commutative ring the polynomial $y^2-a\in A[y]$ is irreducible iff $a$ is not a square in $A$.
Apply to $a=x^3\in A=K[x]$.

Answer (score 4):

To prove that $x^3-y^2\in K[x,y]$ is irreducible. We treat it as polynomial in $K(y)[x]$. Then it has degree $3$. Since there is no $f(y)\in K(y)$ such that $f(y)^3 - y^2=0$. We see that $x^3-y^2$ is irreducible in $K(y)[x]$, hence irreducible in $K[y][x]$.